# PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object (JSON)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json, request

I have an issue that made me scratch my head for a whole day...
I'm trying to retrieve my JSON objects but it can't retrieve the data.

I'm making a GET request. 
If **'id'** is empty it should retrieve ALL my notes in the arraylist of my DB (PHPMyAdmin). Any ideas?

The error I get is this:

```
PHP VERSION: 5.6.21 Connected Successfully 
<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Trying to get property of non-object in
<b>C:\xampp\htdocs\notes.php</b> on line
<b>165</b>
<br />
{
    "header": {
        "msg": "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''notes' WHERE id=6' 
at line 1",
                "code": 400
            },
            "body": []
        }
```

**This is the code**

```
          else if ($method === 'GET')
{
    $sql = "";

    if(empty($_REQUEST['id']))
    {
        // GET All Notes
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'notes' ORDER BY created_date DESC";
    }
    else
    {
      //Get one Note
      $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM 'notes' WHERE id=$id";
    }

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0) //LINE 165 <------- ERROR!!
    {
      $body = array();
      //output data for each row
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      {
        array_push($body, $row);
      }

      $json =
      [
        'header' =>
        [
            'msg' => "OK - Everything is working",
            'code' => 200
        ],
        'body' => $body
      ];
      echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    else
    {
      $json =
      [
        'header' =>
        [
            'msg' => $conn->error,
            'code' => 400
        ],
        'body' => []
      ];
      echo json_encode($json, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
    $conn->close();
}
     ?>
```

Comment: `'notes'` <-- table name is not a string but an identifier. Remove quotes.

Comment: remove the quotes or replace them with: `

Comment: Thank you so much guys!
It worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[PDO::query()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php) returns a PDOStatement object, or FALSE on failure, so you should write row 165 like this:

```
if($result && $result->num_rows > 0)
```